# Android GridView row height is last column's row's height

Tags: android, listview, layout, gridview, format

So I have a gridview of expandable views (user taps on them and they animate to expand). The thing is that my gridview only grows the row height when I click on the second column. In the first picture, you can see I pressed the first item in the list and it expanded but the gridview did not update its rows' heights. In the second picture, I clicked on the second item in the second column and it and the gridview expanded as intended. It seems the gridview is only measuring based on the second column. How can I make it compare it to the first column and pick the larger one? thanks.

EDIT:
This is even happening with plain layouts. The row width is always the second column's height, even if the first column in that row is taller.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I run into the exact same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, to fix it I had to extend GridView and use a couple of dirty hacks...

```
public class AutoGridView extends GridView {
    public AutoGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public AutoGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoGridView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(){
    /*This method is called during onLayout. I let the superclass make the hard
    part, then I change the top and bottom of visible items according to their
    actual height and that of their siblings*/

        final int childrenCount = getChildCount();
        if(childrenCount <= 0){ //nothing to do, just call the super implementation
            super.layoutChildren();
            return;
        }

        /*GridView uses the bottom of the last child to decide if and how to scroll.
        UGLY HACK: ensure the last child bottom is equal to the lowest one.
        Since super implementation might invalidate layout I must be sure the old
        value is restored after the call*/
        View v = getChildAt(childrenCount - 1);
        int oldBottom = v.getBottom();
        super.layoutChildren();
        v.setBottom(oldBottom);

        for(int i = 0; i < getNumColumns(); ++i){
            int top = getListPaddingTop();
            for(int j = i; j < childrenCount; j += getNumColumns()){
                v = getChildAt(j);
                /*after setTop v.getHeight() returns a different value,
                that's why I'm saving it...*/
                int viewHeight = v.getHeight();
                v.setTop(top);
                top += viewHeight;
                v.setBottom(top);
                top += getVerticalSpacing();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int childrenCount = getChildCount();
        if(getAdapter() != null && childrenCount > 0){
            measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            int width = getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightMode = getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

            int maxHeight = heightSize;
            for(int i = 0; i < getNumColumns(); ++i){
                int columnHeight = 0;
                for(int j = i; j < childrenCount; j += getNumColumns())
                    columnHeight += getChildAt(j).getMeasuredHeight() + getVerticalSpacing();
                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, columnHeight);
            }

            getChildAt(childrenCount-1).setBottom(maxHeight); // for the scrolling hack

            int height = heightSize;
            if(heightMode == UNSPECIFIED)
                height = maxHeight;
            else if(heightMode == AT_MOST)
                height = Math.min(maxHeight, heightSize);

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

I know, probably for you this answer is too late, but I hope it can help whoever is stumbling upon your question like I did ^^